# Cauchy integral formula for n=1

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on proving cauchy integral formula (C.I.F) for $n=1$:
$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz.$$ 
Is there another method rather than taking $z= z_0+re^{i \theta}$, putting it in the integral, then letting $r$ shrink to zero?

Comment: Why would you want an alternative to such a splendid idea?

Comment: @zhw, I need a second method of proof, is the method i have mentioned above unique??

Comment: @zhw.  Is there a second method to solve

Comment: No, check Conway's proof in his Complex Analysis book.

Comment: @JoseAntonio can u send me a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(integration by substitution)

$z(t) = a + \epsilon e^{it}$  where $0 ≤ t ≤ 2π $and $ε$ is the radius of the circle.

Letting $ε → 0$ gives the desired estimate

$\begin{align}
\left | \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \,dz  - f(a) \right |
&= \left | \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a} \,dz \right |\\[.5em]
&= \left | \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{f(z(t))-f(a)}{\varepsilon\cdot e^{i\cdot t}}\cdot\varepsilon\cdot e^{i\cdot t}i\right )\,dt\right |\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ |f(z(t)) - f(a)| } {\varepsilon} \,\varepsilon\,dt\\[.5em]
&\leq \max_{|z-a|=\varepsilon}|f(z) - f(a)|
\xrightarrow[\varepsilon\to 0]{} 0.
\end{align}$